# Permission Error - MacOS - open /Users/username/.docker/.token_seed: permission denied

Tags: bash, macos, docker, docker-compose, sudo

I am relatively new to `Docker`, `bash` and `macOS`.

I get a permission denied error when I run a `bash` script that is doing some automation and running `docker-compose`. It works if I run it with `sudo` but I need to run it without `sudo` for a work task. Initially, this `bash` script would error out somewhere earlier on a `copy` with a permission denied error (without `sudo`) tbut I managed to fix this by running `chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/directory` where `/path/to/directory` is where this `bash` script is located.

I need to run this `bash` script without `sudo`. As can be seen from the picture below, the command works with `sudo` (green). The script fails when running without `sudo` as can be seen in red.

What can I do to get rid of this permission denied error underlined in red? Thanks in advance.

[image: Picture of Bash script working with Sudo but not working without Sudo]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: That explains the downvote I assume, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Not my downvote actually, but fixing that would definitely improve your question.

Comment: Actually, there are solid reasons why voting is anonymous, and why this is extremely unlikely to ever change.This is a common FAQ on [meta]; see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Answer (score 1):

In docker compose and dockerfiles, the default user is root. Use the same user as the you would run the script as. You are able to run the container as the user you are logged as on the container's host machine.

You could create the same user with the same ID as you are on the host machine, this is recommended when using docker volumes.

For example,

When running docker build

```
docker image build \
    --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u ${USER}) \
    --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g ${USER}) \
    -t php_test \
    .
```

The user you are using on your host machine is passed through to the docker container, if you want to run the script as the same user.

The dockerfile

```
FROM jtreminio/php:7.2

ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

RUN if [ ${USER_ID:-0} -ne 0 ] && [ ${GROUP_ID:-0} -ne 0 ]; then \
    userdel -f www-data &&\
    if getent group www-data ; then groupdel www-data; fi &&\
    groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} www-data &&\
    useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g www-data www-data &&\
    install -d -m 0755 -o www-data -g www-data /home/www-data
```

The `USER_ID` and `GROUP_ID` arguments are passed through and the container's user and group are deleted, and created again using the arguments provided when running the docker build command.

You scenario you may not need to go as far as this. The code example from the following article, https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not try it because `Docker` is still a blackbox for me and the "solution" I have required less changes.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me fix it was this: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1936

I had to do `docker pull imageName` where `imageName` are the `imageName`s in red in the terminal. I am not sure why this was happening but this seems to have fixed it.